# document.execCommand() does not work with content such as "<something>"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a simple web text editor where an user can write some text/code and when user selects/highlight a part of the content by mouse and click a button the selected/highlighted text/code piece wrap up within `<code></code>` tags dynamically(similar to Stack Overflow editor). To do that I'm using below js

```
$('#AppltCodeWrap').click (function (){
    var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0),
        targetContent = range.commonAncestorContainer.innerHTML;
    document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<code class="prettyprint">' + targetContent + '</code>');
    //....
});
```

This works fine as long as the user content does not contain text such as `<stdio.h>`. When user text contains `<stdio.h>` the above javascript removes such piece of text (I mean only `<stdio.h>` and rest of the selected content remain unharmed).

Also noticed that if the user text/code contains html tags such as `<div><span>Hello</span><div>` above javascript works well. How do I fix that?

I'm using `<div contenteditable = true></div>` as text editor. I'm also using the below instead of `document.getSelection()` to support line breaks.

```
var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0),
    targetContent = range.commonAncestorContainer.innerHTML;
```